# How to bind datatable to ajax loaded tables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using bootstrap nav-tabs. tabs content are loaded via ajax and there are two tables within ajax loaded content. I want to bind datatable jquery plugin for these tables but I don't know how. I know I have to use 'delegate' method but I know where and how.

Thank you.

Comment: what you reference is about load data of datatable via ajax, what I've asked is another question. apply datatable to content of tabs which is loaded via ajax.

Comment: thank you but it is not about my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to bind it after the ajax ajax is complete. This is a way to do this.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file',
        type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
        dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
        data: {param1: 'value1'},
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {

        // after the ajax is complete, this function is 
        // called and you can bind the datatable function on your table
        $('#tableID').dataTable();

        console.log("complete");
    });
```